# minimum specs for the NTP server

Tags: ntp

What are the minimum specs needed for one NTP server? I want to config NTP server like this as shown below :

```
1>$ sudo apt install ntp
2>$ cat /etc/ntp.conf
3>$ sudo nano /etc/ntp.conf          <add the lines in your config file by using nano>
<make change on ntp file>
```

```
##########################
# Leap seconds definition provided by tzdata
leapfile /usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list

# Enable this if you want statistics to be logged.
#statsdir /var/log/ntpstats/

statistics loopstats peerstats clockstats
filegen loopstats file loopstats type day enable
filegen peerstats file peerstats type day enable
filegen clockstats file clockstats type day enable


# Specify one or more NTP servers.

#server 0.asia.pool.ntp.org iburst
#server 1.asia.pool.ntp.org iburst
#server 2.asia.pool.ntp.org iburst                <iburst option for performance>

server 127.127.1.0 prefer
fudge 127.127.1.0 stratum 10                

# Use Ubuntu's ntp server as a fallback.
#pool ntp.ubuntu.com

# Access control configuration; see /usr/share/doc/ntp-doc/html/accopt.html for
# details.  The web page <http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Support/AccessRestrictions>
# might also be helpful.
#
# Note that "restrict" applies to both servers and clients, so a configuration

# that might be intended to block requests from certain clients could also end
# up blocking replies from your own upstream servers.

# By default, exchange time with everybody, but don't allow configuration.
restrict -4 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery limited
restrict -6 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery limited

# Local users may interrogate the ntp server more closely.
restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict ::1

# Needed for adding pool entries
#restrict source notrap nomodify noquery

# Clients from this (example!) subnet have unlimited access, but only if
# cryptographically authenticated.
restrict x.x.x.x mask 255.255.255.0 nomodify notrap
#restrict 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 nomodify notrap

# If you want to provide time to your local subnet, change the next line.
# (Again, the address is an example only.)
#broadcast 192.168.123.255

# If you want to listen to time broadcasts on your local subnet, de-comment the
# next lines.  Please do this only if you trust everybody on the network!
#disable auth
#broadcastclient                
#########################
```

```
4>$ sudo systemctl restart ntp   < Restart the NTP service for the changes to take effect>
5>$ sudo systemctl status ntp     <check status NTP service>
```

I need to know what are the minimum specs needed for the NTP server for 100 host or 1000 hosts? Is there a difference?

Comment: I used to run an NTP server on a 486 pc, so I doubt that the minimum specs need to be high. I guess you'll probably need to try it

Comment: CPU, memory, disk etc. requirements are so minimal that can be ignored. However, depending on the client requests, the network demand may be high. But, for 100 to 1000 clients it will be small (< 1 Mbps).

Answer (score 0):

In short: if you have 1 million clients, you can recycle the oldest PCs in your desktop fleet as dedicated NTP servers, and they'll probably be fine.

NTP puts minimal load on a system, and you can run millions of clients on a fairly low-spec machine.  See [this post](https://serverfault.com/a/813122/129161) for some example stats of a VM I used ran in the public pool.  It normally served around 1.5 M unique clients per day, and during the [Great Snapchat Surge of 2016](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTP_server_misuse_and_abuse#Snapchat_on_iOS), it easily handled double that (see graph below).

[image: Beginning of Snapchat NTP surge]

A couple of other notes on your post:

1. You should not use the local clock as a fallback.  This has been deprecated for many years; orphan mode is preferred.
2. You should never plan to provide just one NTP server.  Four is a useful working minimum.  See [my blog post](https://libertysys.com.au/2016/12/the-school-for-sysadmins-who-cant-timesync-good-and-wanna-learn-to-do-other-stuff-good-too-part-5-myths-misconceptions-and-best-practices/#putting-it-all-together-sample-ntp-configurations) for some specific recommendations on configuration.